# Micro SD Card Suddenly not Recognized in Phone Slot Only

Tags: sd-card, storage, 6.0-marshmallow, moto-x, formatting

This has been bothering me for weeks. I have an android phone (Moto X Pure) that allows for an external storage card to be added. I have one SD card that I was using for a while but I got a new one that I wanted to switch to. The first time I put this card in my phone, it saw it and was happily ready to format it and everything. I accidentally formatted it as a media transfer card instead of an addition to internal storage so I took it out to format it on my computer (with fat32) but when I put the card back in the phone, it wasn't detected. At all. All of my computers seem to like it just fine, a friend's phone was even okay with it. It is literally only my phone that seems to have issues with it. My other micro SD cards are fine in my phone as well. If I connect the SD card through the USB port, the phone recognizes it, but only as a file transfer drive.

I've tried rebooting the device, formatting the card, formatting the card from another phone, and trying to find the card with a file manager from both the phone and a computer with the phone hooked up to it. It seems as though that one SD card just refuses to work with that one slot!

Any help getting the micro SD card to work in my phone would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are chances that mobile formatting created a hidden partition, so you better perform through format and delete any hidden partition. That should help.

Comment: What process exactly did you follow to format it?

Answer (score 1):

You may be experiencing some specific partitioning incompatibility. Try to compare the partition table of cards mountable in your phone with the unmountable card.
Here are some things you might want to take note of:

1. File systems (exFAT, FAT32, ext4, etc).
2. GPT vs. MBR.
3. Hidden partitions or unused spaces preceding the main data partition.